# How to convert my Random Forest Regression model to predict multiple steps into the future

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

So I have created a Random Forest Regression model to predict the prices of the "RRP" column of my dataset. As shown in my code below, this method is trained and validated on my existing dataset for the RRP column, where I am taking in multiple columns to train the model (Multivariate data).

My aim is to predict the next 12 intervals (rows) for the RRP into the future. Could someone please run me through how to perform future predictions with my code below, or recommend any sites that perform a similar procedure. Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline 

# Import csv file 
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Trader1/Desktop/ABSModel/MultiVariable-CQ3/EDABoosting/SA-VICdataEditHourLog.csv')
# Features present in csv
df.head()

df.describe()

df.dtypes

for x in df:
    if df[x].dtypes == "int64":
        df[x] = df[x].astype(float)
        print (df[x].dtypes)

X = df.drop('RRP', axis=1)
Y = df['RRP']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=48, random_state=0)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor 
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 3000, random_state=0)

regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)

Y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

df=pd.DataFrame({'Actual':Y_test, 'Predicted':Y_pred})
df

from sklearn import metrics
print('MAE: Actual RRP vs CQ Predictions', metrics.mean_absolute_error(Y_test, Y_pred))
print('MSE: Actual RRP vs CQ Predictions', metrics.mean_squared_error(Y_test, Y_pred))
print('RMSE: Actual RRP vs CQ Predictions', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(Y_test, Y_pred)))

print("")

print('MAE: Actual RRP vs AEMO FC', metrics.mean_absolute_error(Y_test, (X_test['RRP_FC'])))
print('MSE: Actual RRP vs AEMO FC', metrics.mean_squared_error(Y_test, (X_test['RRP_FC'])))
print('RMSE: Actual RRP vs AEMO FC', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(Y_test, (X_test['RRP_FC']))))

# Calculate the absolute errors
errors = abs(Y_pred - Y_test)
# Print out the mean absolute error (mae)
print('Mean Absolute Error:', round(np.mean(errors), 2), 'degrees.')

# Calculate mean absolute percentage error (MAPE)
mape = 100 * (errors / Y_test)
# Calculate and display accuracy
accuracy = 100 - np.mean(mape)
print('Accuracy:', round(accuracy, 2), '%.')

import seaborn as sns
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 15))

Y = np.array(Y_test)
FC = np.array(X_test['RRP_FC'])

ax1 = plt.plot(Y, color='black') # Actual
ax2 = plt.plot(Y_pred, color='blue') # Predictions
ax3 = plt.plot(FC, color='green') #AEMO FC
plt.legend(ax1,['Actual'])
plt.legend(ax2,['Predictions'])
#ax = sns.distplot(Y, hist=False, color="r", label="Actual Value")
#sns.distplot(Y_pred, hist=False, color="b", label="Fitted Values" , ax=ax)


plt.title('Actual vs Fitted Values for Price')


plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: Plotted results of the predictions vs the actual RRP]

The format of the data set is depicted in the image below (Note: there are 23 columns, but can just use the six that are depicted):
[image: Dataset]

The following image shows the final data set with actualand predicted RRP values:
[image: Final dataset of the trained model]

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question without knowing what "X" contains? Are those date related features?  Please explain the feature set.

Comment: apologies @sharathnatraj I should of been more clear with that, so the X is all of the columns/features that are used to train the model. The Y is just the "RRP" as this is the column I am trying to predict.

Comment: Thats fine. When you say that you want to predict 12 rows intp the future, does it mean that "X" involve time related features. Do you want to predict for 12 days, 12 months or 12 years?

Comment: @sharathnatraj, so the data that is inserted via the csv is in time series format, where it is in 5min intervals. So all of the features (X) are involved with their relative 5min interval for each row. So I essentially want to predict the next hour (12x5min intervals)

Comment: Can you please edit this post and show the tail of the df for last 10 rows. ````df.tail(10)````.

Comment: @sharathnatraj sure thing, I will do that now

Comment: @sharathnatraj I also put in the resulting dataset with the trained model predictions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232790/discussion-between-sharathnatraj-and-workerguy21).